# Tratamiento de clases

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este código cuenta con una clase y con método de inicialización. Los objetos de la clase tendrán dos atributos, llamados horas y minutos

```
Horas = valores comprendidos en el rango de 0-23

Minutos = valores comprendidos en el rango de 0-59
```

**Mi duda viene aquí:**

Los valores para ambos atributos se pasarán en la expresión constructora. No sé si el siguiente código que adjunto es correcto dado que, no comprendo que es la **expresión constructura de los atributos**

```
class Tiempo:

    horas = Time()
    minutos = Time()
    def __init__(self, horas, minutos):
        t1 = Tiempo(6, 30)
        t2 = Tiempo(14, 45)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La **expresión constructora o método constructor** hace referencia a una *funcionalidad* que ya existe dentro del lenguaje, en este caso en Python es por medio de `__init__` cuyas funcionalidades son:

- Se inicializa cuando la clase ha sido instanciada
- Indica el número de argumentos o valores que la clase espera recibir para asignar a cada uno de los parámetros que le fueron declarados
- Para acceder a la funcionalidad de este método no es necesario declarar un acceso a el de forma explçicita
- Los valores que este método espera se declaran en la instancia de la clase y van entre paréntesis
- El uso de este método constructor **no sustituye** la necesidad de declarar otros métodos que operen con los valores que tu has declarado, pues como notas su funcionalidad esta pensada para otras necesidades

Es decir tu método constructor son estas líneas:

```
def __init__(self, horas, minutos):
  self.horas = horas 
  self.minutos = minutos
```

Donde a las pseudovariables:

- `self.horas`
- `self.minutos`

Las igualamos o les asignamos el valor que reciben de cada uno de los argumentos, es decir que si en la instancia pasamos como valores: **(10, 20)**; entonces internamente se vería de esta forma:

```
self.horas = 10
self.minutos = 20
```

Donde se le indica que una vez que la clase se instancie va a requerir 2 valores, una para asignarlo a la propiedad `horas` y el último para la propiedad `tiempo`.

Lo anterior lo logramos cuando asignamos a un objeto la instancia de la clase, del modo siguiente:

Aquí a la clase le indicamos entre paréntesis los valores que espera recibir

```
miTiempo = Tiempo(10, 30)
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior la clase:

- Se encuentra instanciada a nivel del objeto `miTiempo`
- Ha recibido los 2 valores que espera para sus 2 propiedades
- Sin embargo no tiene lógica alguna declarada para operar dichos valores, por eso si verificas este código no dará error pero tampoco mostrará valor alguno.

Considera que de seguir la sintaxis que coloco al inicio, entonces el objeto espera que para la instancia le des 2 valores, en caso contrario te daría un error de este tipo:

> TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument:

Si por otro lado tu deseas desde el cuerpo de la clase darle un valor *por default* a una de las propiedades, entonces tu ejemplo debería quedar de este modo:

**Código**

```
class Tiempo:
    horas = ""
    minutos = ""
    def __init__(self, horas, minutos):
      self.horas = 17
      self.minutos = minutos 
    def operaTiempo(self):
      return str(self.horas)+":"+str(self.minutos)

tiempo = Tiempo(12, 10)
print(tiempo.operaTiempo())
```

Que te dará como resultado:

> 17:10

Lo anterior lo logramos haciendo:

- Primero la instancia y pasando en este entre parentesis los argumentos necesarios que espera la clase
- Posterior ese mismo objeto `tiempo` le indicamos que acceda al método `operTiempo()` para de este extraer el resultado que la lógica interna genera con los valores que dimos en la línea anterior

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda. Gracias a ti he podido entender el concepto :)